# Dynamic header with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I know this is a basic PHP question, and I'm trying to learn the stuff. I very familiar with HTML, CSS and familiar with the CONCEPT of PHP, but not with specifics.

I have always partnered with a back end developer to accomplish this stuff and to set up wordpress sites, etc.

I'm building a very basic four or five page website (a showcase for the client's custom fishing rods: http://www.tuscaroratackle.com/index2.php). I want to call the page header (as in logo, navigation, etc., not as in the head element) dynamically from a php file, and same thing with the footer, so I don't have to rewrite all the markup on every page for these bits.

I don't intend to use a database for this site, I was just thinking I could call those two bits from another file, as you would in a wordpress setup with the header.php in the wp-content directory.

Is there an easy explanation on how to do this? (I get the basics, just looking for help on the more specific PHP calls that need to be made)

Or, if this is not an answer somebody could easy give, can you point me to a good resource to research it further?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You betcha - [include and require](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) -

using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

in your page:

```
<body>
  <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

in your header.php

```
<div id="header">
   <!-- content -->
   <?php echo "run php stuff too"; ?>
</div>
```

would result in:

```
<body>
   <div id="header">
     <!-- content -->
     run php stuff too
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should put the header html code in some file such as `header.php` and then include it with php like:

```
include ('header.php');
```

You should specify the correct path there, for example, if you put the `header.php` file in `includes` folder, you can include it like:

```
include ('inclues/header.php');
```

More Info:

http://php.net/include

Comment: Did you notice how we both got -1 votes? Guess we must have missed the mark for somebody, lol

Comment: Well from the askers perspective - you both got +1. Very helpful both of you. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put in a separate file and use `include`, `require` or  `require_once`.

Eg

```
require_once("path/to/myfile.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into PHP includes.

The way I normally do it is to create a file called includes.php with two functions header() and footer(), then call them on each page like such:

includes.php:

```
<?php
function header(){
   echo '<div id="header">Welcome</div>';
}

function footer(){
   echo '<div id="footer">Goodbye</div>';
}
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
   include_once('includes.php');
   header();
   echo '<div id="content">Main page body</div>';
   footer();
```

?>